# Delphi: What is the escape character in filter string of a Data access such as TVirtualTable

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I am trying a build a filter string for a Virtual table and would like underscore (_) to be a literal character and cannot figure out the escape character. Following are few that I tried and failed miserably:

```
VTAllDocs.Filter :='FILE_NAME like '+QuotedStr(MQDRegister.FieldByName('DOC_ID').AsString+'%\_REV%');
```

AND

```
VTAllDocs.Filter :='FILE_NAME like '+QuotedStr(MQDRegister.FieldByName('DOC_ID').AsString+'%[_]REV%');
```

AND

```
VTAllDocs.Filter :='FILE_NAME like '+QuotedStr(MQDRegister.FieldByName('DOC_ID').AsString+'*\_REV*');
```

AND

```
VTAllDocs.Filter :='(FILE_NAME like '+QuotedStr(MQDRegister.FieldByName('DOC_ID').AsString+'%^_REV%)+' ESCAPE "^")';
```

Really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind..

Contacted DevArt support desk and they said there is no escape character for underscore (_), so now I loop through the rows and do the checking manually.